# Generate thumbnail code generates blank image with 644 permission

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, file-permissions

I am using custom thumbnail code to generate thumbnails of woo commerce products. It was working fine few days ago. But suddenly, it stopped working. Recently, php version is updated to 7.0.20. I think its an issue with this but didn't found any solution yet.

Here is the thumbnail code i am using:

```
 function image_product_resize_crop_white_bg ( $src, $w, $h, $dest = null, $override = false, $createNewIfExists = false ) {     
    $ext = array_pop ( explode ('.', $src) );       
    $filenameSrc = str_replace (".$ext", '', basename($src) );      
    $filename = "{$filenameSrc}-{$w}X{$h}";     
    $arrayUploadPath = wp_upload_dir();     
    $fileUploadSubDir = "/product/";        
    $fileUploadDir = $arrayUploadPath['basedir'] . "/product/";
    if(is_null($dest)) $dest = $fileUploadDir;              
    $i = null;      
    if( ! $override && $createNewIfExists ) {           
        $i = 0;         
        while ( file_exists("$dest$filename-$i.png") ) $i++;            
            $i = '-' . $i;      
    }               
    $fileFullPath = "$dest$filename$i.png";     
    $fileFullUrl = $arrayUploadPath['baseurl'] . $fileUploadSubDir . $filename.$i .'.png';
    if( ! $override && file_exists($fileFullPath) ) return $fileFullUrl;
    if( $override ) @unlink($fileFullPath);
    switch ($ext) {         
        case 'jpg':         
        case 'jpeg' : $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;            
        case 'gif' : $image = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;          
        case 'png' : $image = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;          
        case 'wbmp' :           
        case 'bmp': $image = imagecreatefromwbmp($src); break;          
        default: $image = imagecreatefromgd2($src);     
    }               
    $width = imagesx($image);       
    $height = imagesy($image);          
    $original_aspect = $width / $height;        
    $thumb_aspect = $w / $h;                
    if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect ) {          
        if( $width > $w ) {             
            $new_height = $h;               
            $new_width = $width / ($height / $h);           
        }else{              
            $new_height = $height;              
            $new_width = $width;            
        }                   
    } else {           
        if ( $width > $w ) {              
            $new_width = $w;               
            $new_height = $height / ($width / $w);         
        } else {              
            $new_width = $width;              
            $new_height = $height;         
        }       
    }
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

    imagealphablending($thumb, false);
    imagesavealpha($thumb, true);

    $transparent = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($thumb, $transparent);
    imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $w, $h, $transparent);



    imagecopyresampled($thumb,$image,0-($new_width - $w) / 2,0 - ($new_height - $h) / 2,0, 0,$new_width, $new_height,$width, $height);
    imagepng($thumb, $fileFullPath, 9);
    imagedestroy($image);
    return $fileFullUrl;
}
```

Using this code, blank thumbnails are generating with 644 permission. Earlier, thumbnails were generating with 755 permission.

But, uploading images in media of wordpress admin panel generating images properly.

Can anyone help me fix this issue. My site is live and thumnails are not generating.

Comment: Normally all files permissions should be 644 and folder permission should be 755. So now you say "blank thumbnails are generating with 644 permission" which is correct but not the ones "Earlier" with 755…

Comment: I agree that normally files generate with 644 and folder with 755 then what is the issue in my code that it is generating blank thumbnail.

Comment: When i am uploading images from media from admin panel, it's generating thumbnails in the uploads folder and i checked that the thumbnails are generating with 644 permission and are not blank. It means the bug is in my script.

Comment: Sorry but this is more a classic WP/PHP question and I am not skill enough to find out what is wrong…